# How to check if AppEngine application version already exists programmatically

Tags: java, google-app-engine, shell, deployment, continuous-integration

Is it possible to check if an application version is already deployed to AppEngine using the appcfg shell or Python script? I'm automating our deployments to AppEngine and want to safeguard against overwriting an existing version.

Comment: I think you can urlfetch the version you are looking for and check if the request goes in 404 error

Comment: That's an excellent suggestion! Some of our environments require users to authenticate with their Google account, though. So the 404 won't be returned before you are logged on. Do you have any how I can integrate that with a URL fetch?

Comment: If the login page is shown than a version exists. You need to check the absolute existence of a version, or if a single page is reachable?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I always get the logon-screen regardless if the version is valid (e.g. http://doesnotexist.my-application.appspot.com). It seems to fallback on the default version if the version is unknown. No redirect, though.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible if you let your app serve an url for which you don't have to log in with a google account which then shows a bunch of info that your script can use.
For example https://yourapp.appspot.com/info could display version information.

It looks like version info is now available serverside if you use the new Modules api:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/labs/modules/ModulesService#getVersions(java.lang.String)